# PHP - Get the days of the current week

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to display the current week dates but i'm having some issues when the day changes.
Here's my code:

```
$monday = strtotime("last monday");
$monday= date('w', $monday)==date('w') ? $monday+7*86400 : $monday; 

    if(date('D')!='Mon'){                      //seleziona il giorno corrente
        $monday= date('d-m-Y',strtotime('last Monday'));       //recupera l'ultimo giorno della settimana interessato
    }else{
        $monday= date('d-m-Y');   
    }
```

So I'm doing the same with the other days of the week, but, once the days pass by, it takes the days of the week before this.

For example, if today is Monday and my code for the other days is:

```
$tuesday= strtotime("next tuesday");
$tuesday= date('w', $tuesday)==date('w') ? $tuesday+7*86400 : $tuesday; 

    if(date('D')!='Tue'){                     
        $tuesday= date('d-m-Y',strtotime('next Tuesday'));  
    }else{
        $tuesday= date('d-m-Y');   
    }
```

The echo of $monday and $tuesday would be ok for today, but tomorrow $tuesday will change to the next week tuesday.

How can i fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try using: `$monday=date(Y-m-d,strtotime('monday this week'))` , can use it for all other days or you can loop when u get the timestamp from monday?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296481/352329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user Naruto gave a nice solution in the comment section:

```
$monday=date(Y-m-d,strtotime('monday this week'))
```

The "this week" seems to work fine for the purpose.